# how to store random generated numbers in arrays. Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
mov bx,0
mov cx,0
copy:

;copy col arrays.
mov dl,[col_star+bx]
mov [go_right+bx],dl
mov [go_left+bx],dl
inc [go_right+bx]
dec [go_left+bx]

;copy row arrays
mov dl,[row_star+bx]
mov [go_up+bx],dl
mov [go_down+bx],dl
dec [go_up+bx]
inc [go_down+bx]

inc bx
inc cx
cmp cx,20
jl copy
```

say i have 20 values for col_star db 20 dup(?) and row_star db 20 dup(?)
will this loop copy the values in each array. i need to manipulate per value. 
thats why there is an inc/dec. been trying to this loop for hours already nothinghappening.

Answer (score 1):

```
mov bl,0      ;use BX !!!
transfer:

call random_coor_star
mov dl, gen_row_star
mov [row_star+bx],dl

mov dl, gen_col_star
mov [col_star+bx],dl
inc bl        ;use BX !!!
 PUSH BX
call delay
 PUSH BX
cmp bx,20
jl transfer
```

In the previous code snippet you need to use BX in stead of BL.

EDIT

To store 20 values change `cmp bx,5` and `jle transfer` into `cmp bx,20` and `jl transfer`.
Best make sure that *delay* preserves all registers.

```
transfer:
call delay
call random_coor_star
mov dl, gen_row_star
mov [row_star+bx],dl
mov dl, gen_col_star
mov [col_star+bx],dl
complete_print [row_star+bx],[col_star+bx],star_char,color
inc bx

cmp bx,5
jle transfer
```

Comment: im i doing it right? i dont why it doesnt store 20 values. the loop should do about 20 values stored in row_star db 20 dup(?)
col_star db 20 dup(?)

Comment: Yes. You fill two 20-byte arrays with numbers from 5-9 (row) and 5-54 (column) respectively.

Comment: ill post my code. it seems to have many bugs. i do not understand the loop.

Comment: You forget that calling _delay_ messes up the BX register!

Comment: can you help me? im having difficulty stroring the random generate numbers inside the arrays. they dont seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Little program to store 20 pairs of random numbers in an array (with EMU8086 and your random algorithm) :

```
.stack 100h
.data            

gen_row_star db ?
gen_col_star db ?

array db 40 dup(?)  ;STORES 20 PAIRS OF RANDOM NUMBERS.

.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;FILL ARRAY WITH RANDOM NUMBERS.
  mov  di, offset array
  mov  bp, 20  ;GENERATE 20 PAIRS OF RANDOM NUMBERS.
fill_array:
  call random_coor_star ;NUMBERS RETURN IN gen_row_star AND gen_col_star.
  mov  al, gen_col_star 
  mov  [ di ], al
  inc  di  ;POSITION FOR NEXT NUMBER IN CURRENT PAIR.
  mov  al, gen_row_star 
  mov  [ di ], al
  inc  di  ;POSITION FOR NEXT PAIR.
  dec  bp
  jnz  fill_array

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h           

;------------------------------------------
;DR.DOOM'S RANDOM PROC.

random_coor_star proc

mov ah, 00h
int 1ah

mov ah, 00h
int 1ah

mov ax,dx
xor dx,dx
mov cx,10
div cx

add dl, 5
mov al,dl
mov gen_row_star,al

mov ah, 00h
int 1ah

mov ah, 00h
int 1ah

mov ax,dx
xor dx,dx
mov cx,50
div cx
add dl,5
mov al,dl
mov gen_col_star,al

ret

random_coor_star endp
```

Comment: dude, i finally found a way to make a loop :)))) finally after many hrs :<

Comment: done passing the values of the array, done manipulating. but cant do a loop to print the new coordinates for my character.

Comment: Go take a look to your other question about printing coordinates  :)